# How to compile cocos2d-x on android(I have some errors)

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I wrote a code of window and now I want to compile it on android.
Earlier, I compiled a blank project and successfully launched it.
But my project recompile errors, I do not really understand their origin. Attached is a screen below.

[image]

Comment: Edit your post and paste the code as text.  Many people don't have access to those links.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all .cpp (and not .h) files you created in Android.mk file. Add them in LOCAL_SRC_FILES.

For example:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/PlayScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/Utils.cpp
```

Then you can try running your app. Best method is to run it from console, because eclipse has problems with c++ (to be honest it only runs build_native.py):

```
cocos run -p android
```